# Example of sequence with a specific property

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $b>0$ and $c\in[0,1)$.
Does exist a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\rightarrow a$ such that the following inequality holds$$
|x_n-a|<bc^n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N},
$$ but the inequality$$
|x_{n+1}-a|<c|x_n-a|, \forall n\in \mathbb{N},
$$ does not hold?
I started with the sequence $(q^n)$, with $q\in(0,1)$, and I tried to perturbated somehow, but I get stuck.

Comment: What about $x_n = (b-\epsilon)c^n + a$, where $\epsilon >0$ such that $b - \epsilon > 0$? Then $|x_n - a| = (b-\epsilon)c^n < bc^n$, but $|x_{n+1}-a| = (b-\epsilon)c^{n+1} = c(b-\epsilon)c^n = c|x_n -a|$

Comment: Very interesting. Does this example works if we change $<$ with $<=$ in both inequalities? I don't know how to insert $<=$ and that is why I don't put it in the question.